# connect react.js to Google Collab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, machine-learning, flask, google-colaboratory

I want to make a simple image classification app such that the training/classification is done in a Python script. I want to create a web app for it (preferably in React.js) where the user can select parameters or the activation function etc.

To link the front-end with backend, I was planning to use the flaskAPI. However, since the training data could be large, I wanted to use GoogleColab for the ML/Python part. Is it possible to run my front-end such that it's linked to Google Colab? I couldn't find any relevant examples.

Comment: if you found a solution please post it here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple, step-by-step demo of how to build a Python-Flask application, host it in Google Colab and then access it from the public internet ( using a public URL) using NGROK tunnels. The [demo is available in GitHub Repository](https://github.com/Praxis-QR/DEMD/blob/main/WebApps_V2_1_in_Colab.ipynb). The first five apps have no machine learning component but demonstrate basic input-output abilities. There are two machine learning apps, one with linear regression and one with decision tree that is used for Image Classification. While we do not use React.js we do address the issue of accessing a ML model through a web API. Do note that the ML models have to built separately and should be available for loading into the Colab VM either from Google Drive ( as in this case) or from/through some other mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using Flask.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1F-b8Vv_jaThi55_z0VLYLw3DDVnPYZMp

Comment: I think this is just an example to incorporate flask in colab?